Why am I receiving the error message "some character data was lost during transcoding of the lib21.accident and lib22.accident datasets?
I am conducting a project where I am working with data from the Fatal Analysis Reporting System (FARS) and I have been trying to create a new dataset, which is a subset of the original accident files from 2018-2022 in order to run a macro where I am combining the vehicle and person data for each year. Whenever I try to run the code to create a new dataset that contains the state case and year from the original accident files, I receive the following error messages and notes I received in the log for the 2021 and 2022 accident files.
NOTE: Data file LIB21.ACCIDENT.DATA is in a format that is native to another host, or the file encoding does not match the session encoding. Cross Environment Data Access will be
used, which might require additional CPU resources and might reduce performance.
ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the dataset LIB21.ACCIDENT. Either the data contains characters that are not representable in the new encoding or
truncation occurred during transcoding.
NOTE: Data file LIB22.ACCIDENT.DATA is in a format that is native to another host, or the file encoding does not match the session encoding. Cross Environment Data Access will be
used, which might require additional CPU resources and might reduce performance.
ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the dataset LIB22.ACCIDENT. Either the data contains characters that are not representable in the new encoding or
truncation occurred during transcoding.
data lib18.accident2;
    set lib18.accident;
    keep st_case year;
run;

data lib19.accident2;
    set lib19.accident;
    keep st_case year;
run;

data lib20.accident2;
    set lib20.accident;
    keep st_case year;
run;

data lib21.accident2;
    set lib21.accident;
    keep st_case year;
run;

data lib22.accident2;
    set lib22.accident;
    keep st_case year;
run;

Also, below is the code for the macro I am using to combine the accident, person, vehicle, drug3 and miper files for the 2018-2022 data. Please let me know how I can make this error reproducible because I am not sure how to do that.
%macro doit (yr=);
proc sort data=lib&yr..person; 
by st_case veh_no per_no;
proc sort data=lib&yr..vehicle; 
by st_case veh_no;

data vehper&yr; 
merge lib&yr..vehicle (in=v) lib&yr..person (in=p ); 
by st_case veh_no;
if v;
run;

proc sort data=vehper&yr; 
by st_case veh_no per_no;

proc sort data=lib&yr..miper; 
by st_case veh_no per_no;

proc sort data=lib&yr..drugs3; 
by st_case veh_no per_no;

data lib&yr..vehper&yr;
merge vehper&yr(in=v) lib&yr..miper (in=a) lib&yr..drugs3 (in=b); 
by st_case veh_no per_no;
if v;
run;

data vehper&yr (encoding=UTF-8);
merge lib&yr..vehper&yr (in=a) lib&yr..accident2;
by st_case;
if a;
run;

%mend doit;
%doit (yr=18);
%doit (yr=19);
%doit (yr=20);
%doit (yr=21);
%doit (yr=22);
;

